# VS2015 asmx method not found

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

I am having legacy project which was migrated to visual studio 2015. Everything works well, only asmx action is not found. 
I don't understand what is wrong here? My project runs inside IIS express. 
I've tried to create virtual directory inside IIS and if I open website from IIS asmx works fine.

What I've also tried is to delete and then add .asmx file to project. Nothing changed.

Only within IIS express it doesn't work (when project is run directly from visual studio). Error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:53358/wf/wsSearchCAMERC.asmx/GetBAUSERSearch1

Settings:

[image]

Code:

```
    namespace fCatEve
    {
      /// <summary>
      /// Summary description for wsSearchCAMERC
      /// </summary>
      [WebService(Namespace = "fCatEve")]
      [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
      [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
      // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
      [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
      public class wsSearchCAMERC : System.Web.Services.WebService
      {

     [WebMethod]
        public string[] GetBAUSERSearch1(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
        // code omitted for clarity
        }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by copy-pasting methods from .`asmx` to `MVC` controller, which is asynchronous by default. I can now call those methods with same link as from `.asmx`.